# Loop different tables in type script

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two tables `X {n_fnc : number , name : string :, date : Date }` and `Y{id:number , n_fnc : number , status : String }`.  I want to create a list or a table which contains only the `n_fnc` of table X which have the status in table Y = "act".
For example I take n_fnc from table X and I look for all the rows that have the same n_fnc in table Y if I find that all the rows I found have the status = act I add this n_fnc in a table or a list otherwise I don"t add anything.

```
  n_fncwhohaveallstatusact : number []=[];
this.X.forEach(element => {
    let s= 0;
     let k=0; 
     console.log("element",element  )
     console.log("test")
    this.Y.forEach(org =>{
     if(element.n_fnc=== org.n_fnc){
       if(org.status=='act'){
         s=org.n_fnc
         k=0;
         console.log(s);
       }
       else if(org.status!='act' && org.status!=''){

         k=1
       }
       else{
         k=2
       }
     }



    })
    if(k!= (1 || 2 )  ){
     this.n_fncwhohaveallstatusact .push(s)
    }
```

the console don't show me anything it like he don"t loop the table X with foreach
any suggestion ?

Comment: There is way too much to unpack here. What you're actually trying to achieve is completely unclear to me (after reading the question multiple times), but the two biggest problems I see are 1) you don't seem to be aware of how asynchronous functions behave; and 2) `if(k!= (1 || 2 )  )` does not do what you think it does. Please rephrase your question, provide your expected input and output and clean up and format your code. It's almost unreadable.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I have updated the post maybe it s clear now

Comment: So all the corresponding entries in Y have to have status `act`? Or just one of them? Would be a lot easier if you provided sample data and expected output.

Comment: all status = act

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to achieve this by just using [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```js
const X = [];
const Y = [];

const result = X.map(({n_fnc}) => n_fnc)
                .filter(v => Y.filter(({n_fnc}) => n_fnc === v)
                              .every(({status}) => status === 'act'));
```

Comment: it doesn't show anything when I display result in console log

Comment: See point 1 of my first comment: you don't seem to be aware of how asynchronous functions behave. But since that has been completely edited out of your question, I thought it was no longer relevant.

Comment: I don"t know what is asynchronous functions

Comment: So, any other suggestion ? :/

Comment: You're going to have to learn about asynchronous behavior in JavaScript, in particular RxJS `Observable`s (what you seem to be using). It's not something that can be explained in a couple of comments...

Comment: So what  I understand from what you said, the task I want to achieve is very difficult , it s weird.I can do it easily with java or python but I don"t use typescript

Comment: Have you ever used asynchronous behavior in Java? Using `Executor`s and `Future`s and the likes? Because I can assure you that it's a lot easier in TypeScript with RxJS than in Java using the `java.util.concurrent` package. (Even RxJava is a bit of a hassle to use.) The matching of those two arrays is not your problem, it's the fact that your subscribing to two asynchronous services, but are treating them as if they behave synchronously.

Comment: can we move to discussion chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227030/discussion-between-hamza-nouri-and-robby-cornelissen).